# Sharing Internet Through a Network Interface

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface, ethernet, iproute

I am trying to share internet to another device using USB NCM functionality. I have successfully configured usb0 interface. However, I am not sure how to share internet. So far I have done:

On the host

```
# Add USB interface
ip link add eth0 link usb0 type macvlan
ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1380
# Configure IP address
HOST_USB_IP=10.0.1.1
sudo ifconfig usb0 $HOST_USB_IP netmask 255.255.255.0
ip route
echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward > /dev/null
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE -s 10.0.1.0/24
```

On the target device

```
# Configure IP Address
HOST_USB_IP=10.0.1.1
TARGET_USB_IP=10.0.1.2
ifconfig usb0 $TARGET_USB_IP netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw $HOST_USB_IP
route
```

On host, now I have,

- `eth1`, which is my RJ45-Ethernet connected directly to router-modem, which has internet connection.
- `eth0`, which is what `usb0` is linked to.
- `usb0`, which shares its network with the target device. On target device the connection appears with different name. But, I am able to ping the host device.

I want to be able to connect to the `eth1`'s internet through usb0 from target device. If I try to do so, I get a message saying that eth1 already exists.

What kind of configuration I should do on host to connect usb0 to already existing `eth1`, not `eth0`, which is created upon linking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can your router modem handle multiple "internal" IP addresses (i.e. one for your Linux system and one for the USB-connected device)? If so you might be able to create a bridge with usb0 and eth1. Otherwise you're going to have to continue masquerading eth0/usb0 over eth1. (I can add an answer once you've clarified what your router expects.)

Comment: As I am pretty new with this, could you post something that I could try? I tried giving IP address from same subnet as eth1 to usb0 in host, seems like its working but the target side can not ping the host.

Comment: You need to address the question I've asked before I can usefully answer you.

Comment: I wonder why you're using macvlan here. It adds an unnecessary layer imho. I would use directly usb0.